# How to create a dataframe with a column name conditional on an object's value in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I want to create a dataframe with a column whose value depends on another object's value.

Here's an example, I want my column to be called "conditional_colname":

```
x = "conditional_colname"
df <- data.frame(x = c(1, 2, 3))
df

>  x
1 1
2 2
3 3
```

I could try the following [indirection syntax in tidy evaluation](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html), but it returns an error:

```
data.frame({{x}} := c(1, 2, 3))
> Error in `:=`({ : could not find function ":="
```

I can sort out the problem through the use of the `rename` function and [indirection in tidy evaluation syntax](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html), as in:

```
df %>% rename({{x}} := x)
>   conditional_colname
1                   1
2                   2
3                   3
```

but that involves creating the dataframe with a wrong name and then renaming it, is there any option to do it from the creation of the dataset?

Comment: You're right, let me edit that in the question.

Comment: I'm a huge fan of the tidy evaluation DLS but an influx of (high-quality!) questions like this indicates that there is substantial confusion over where it can be applied (and/or general confusion over the boundaries between r-lib/tidyverse and core R). This probably needs to be made **much** more explicit in the documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`{{..}}` can be used with `tibbles` -

```
library(tibble)
library(rlang)

df <- tibble({{x}} := c(1, 2, 3))
df

# A tibble: 3 × 1
#  conditional_colname
#                <dbl>
#1                   1
#2                   2
#3                   3
```

---

A solution with data.frame would be with `setNames`.

```
df <- setNames(data.frame(c(1, 2, 3)), x)
```